# How to set default browser window size in Protractor/WebdriverJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

For some reason when I run my tests at work the browser is maximized, but when I run them at home it only opens a browser window of about 50% width. This causes some discrepancies with scrolling down, etc., so I'd ideally like to have it open a browser window of the same size on every machine the tests are run on. What's the best way to do this?

(I've found some answers for other languages, but I haven't been able to adapt them to JavaScript)

Adding

```
browser.executeScript('window.moveTo(0,0);' +
    'window.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);');
```

does nothing (apparently `window.moveTo` and `window.resizeTo` are not supported by Google Chrome).

Comment: I don't have an answer for you at this time, but I can tell you that `window.moveTo` and `window.scrollTo` are definitely supported by Chrome.

Comment: scrollTo works. But the others don't, at least not from what I can tell. Try typing it in the console...does nothing.

Comment: At the risk of getting off-topic, [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3wfk/) that illustrates `window.moveTo` and `window.resizeTo`. It works fine for me in Chrome. I don't know that you can resize the current window from the console in Chrome, but the fact that the `resizeTo` method is available there indicates Chrome supports it.

Comment: Ok, seems to be working for new windows that the browser opens with JS. But does not work with the current window, which is what I need.

Comment: I don't have an answer either, but I would certainly question whether you're doing things right if your test is dependent on screen size or whether the browser is maximised - perhaps it makes sense to refactor your test to not have that dependency?

Comment: My test is for whether or not things work and are visible in different responsive configurations, so I need to be able to control the window size for each test.

Comment: start chrome browser with option --window-size=360,640 can help

Comment: The docs for configuring Protractor https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities suggest `capabilities.chromeOptions.args: "start-maximized"` in the config file (see also 
http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ )

Answer (score 200, accepted):

You can set the default browser size by running:

```
var width = 800;
var height = 600;
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
```

To maximize the browser window, run:

```
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

To set the position, run:

```
var x = 150;
var y = 100;
browser.driver.manage().window().setPosition(x, y);
```

If you get an error:

> WebDriverError: unknown error: operation is unsupported with remote debugging

> Operation not supported when using remote debugging Some WebDriver
> commands (e.g. resizing the browser window) require a Chrome extension
> to be loaded into the browser. ChromeDriver normally loads this
> "automation extension" every time it launches a new Chrome session.
>
> However ChromeDriver can be instructed to connect to an existing
> Chrome session instead of launching a new one. This is done using
> 'debuggerAddress' in the Capabilities (aka ChromeOptions) object.
> Since the automation extension is only loaded at startup, there are
> some commands that ChromeDriver does not support when working with
> existing sessions through remote debugging.
>
> If you see the error "operation not supported when using remote
> debugging", try rewriting the test so that it launches a new Chrome
> session. This can be done by removing 'debuggerAddress' from the
> Capabilities object.

Source: *[Operation not supported when using remote debugging](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/operation-not-supported-when-using-remote-debugging)*

Comment: It's also possible to maximise the browser to the full screen size using `browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();`

Comment: @BenSmith: I mentioned that since my initial answer :)

Comment: If you want to have the same resolution for all of your tests, you can call the above in your `protractor.conf.js` file's `onPrepare` function.

Comment: @BenSmith not sure why, but `browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();` doesn't actually maximize the window for me. I just get a slightly larger window. I just end up specifying a width and height with the `setSize()` method

Comment: `.maximize` doesn't seem to work when you go headless I suppose. I had to specify explicitly the size of the window

Comment: @AlexandrosSpyropoulos : it should work but you have to make sure that you're not running xvfb in some silly resolution. For e.g. by default it's 640x480.

Comment: How would you do to use the same sizes when forking? Do I have to set the size manually then again?

Comment: @Olov what do you mean by forking?

Comment: @RăzvanPanda Oh sorry, I was refering to a Protractor (Angular testing framework) action. You can create new browser windows in Protractor by forking a new driver instance. It would be nice if you could specify some standard dimensions to always open new browser windows in.

Comment: That gives me `WebDriverError: unknown error: operation is unsupported with remote debugging`

Comment: @LeeGee Updated answer.

Comment: Something seems to be missing after *"If you get an error"*.

Answer (score 42):

You can also use your `config.js` to set window size:

```
// config.js
specs: [
    ...
],
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: ['--window-size=800,600'] // THIS!
    }
}
// ....
```

Comment: you need remove double dash : args: ['window-size=800,600']

Comment: This works as expected for me WITH the double dash as shown in the answer.

Comment: This also sets the browser sizes when running e2e scripts with the '--headless' args. Which is handy if menu gets shifted to mobile view.

Answer (score 28):

If the preferred method:

```
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

doesn't work for you (for example running Protractor tests in Xvfb), then you can also maximize window this way (protractor.conf.js):

```
onPrepare: function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        browser.driver.executeScript(function() {
            return {
                width: window.screen.availWidth,
                height: window.screen.availHeight
            };
        }).then(function(result) {
            browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(result.width, result.height);
        });
    });
},
```

TypeScript version:

```
import {Config, browser} from "protractor";

export let config: Config = {
    ...
    onPrepare: () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            browser.driver.executeScript<[number, number]>(() => {
                return [
                    window.screen.availWidth,
                    window.screen.availHeight
                ];
            }).then((result: [number, number]) => {
                browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(result[0], result[1]);
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: best ideea with auto get max resolution, but you forgot setPosition(0, 0) so it will be exactly over the screen

Comment: Hm, my browser already starts at position 0-0. But good point if someone need it.

Comment: mine starts at... 50,50 or something.. just saying :)

Comment: it may depend on the OS, here it's Windows 8.1 run inside Hyper-V

Answer (score 17):

I simply added the code below in my *protractor.conf.js* file and it did work fine.

```
onPrepare: function() {
    var width = 1600;
    var height = 1200;
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
},
```

What purpose does the setTimeout and executeScript serve in your answer? I struggle to find best practices in the protractor documentation...

To my mind, using directly maximize() is a bad idea and should not be the preferred method, since it would not set the same size on every machine where the tests are executed and could break responsive behaviours.

Answer (score 5):

In Protractor.conf.js file add following configuration

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
               'start-maximized'
            ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In Selenium 4 (Protractor 6), `setRect` replaces `setSize` and `setPosition`

For example,

```
browser.driver.manage().window().setRect({height: 600, width: 800});
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your config.js file as per below.

```
onPrepare: function () {
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024); // Width, height
},
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: [ "--start-maximized" ] // To start the browser as maximixed
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to go with `async/await`

You can maximize the window globally (once the browser started) like so

```
// protractor.conf.js

exports.config = {

    async onPrepare() {
        // start browser in specified window size
        await browser.driver
            .manage()
            .window()
            .setSize(1920, 1080);
    },
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the below code. This will maximize the browser window.

```
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. There are already answers that provide this information with much more explanation. Please ensure your answers add something new to the question.