# Getting WebDriver to re-size using protractor and cucumber

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

I have been unable to resize the Selenium WebDriver in my protractor/cucumber testing.

These are some of the commands that I have tried.

```
webdriver.WebDriver.Window().setSize(width, height);
webdriver.WebDriver.Window().setSize(width, height);
webdriver.WebDriver.Window.setSize(width, height);
webdriver.WebDriver.Window.prototype.setSize(width, height);
```

From [here](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.Window.prototype.setSize)

```
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
```

[How to set default browser window size in Protractor/WebdriverJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023567/how-to-set-default-browser-window-size-in-protractor-webdriverjs)

And:

```
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
webdriver.WebDriver.Window.prototype.maximize();
webdriver.WebDriver.Window.maximize();
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

[This](http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/set-browser-width-and-height-in-selenium-webdriver) article, for example, was no help as I don't know where the imports come from.

I have had no luck understanding the root of this issue as they all return promises and I am not sure how to debug them.

I am using protractor version 2.0.0

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Let me guess, you are on `chrome` + `Mac OS`?

Comment: No, I am actually on Windows. But yes, using chrome.

Answer (score 1):

`browser.manage().window().setSize(width, height);` works for me. Notice that I'm not trying to call to `driver` as you do in your examples. My full step def looks like this:

```
this.Given(/^I (?:have|change to|resize to|rotate to) a (\d+)x(\d+) screen size$/, function(width, height, callback) {
  browser.manage().window().setSize(parseInt(width, 10), parseInt(height, 10));
  return callback();
});
```

You can find that and other examples in the [CukeFarm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cukefarm) library. Full disclosure: I helped build that library.