# Protractor : Set browser size - What are we setting here in the browser

Tags: selenium, protractor

When we do a browser set size in protractor what exactly are we setting in the browser ->window - innerwidth and height, document width and height or something else?

I have a test where browser size should be 1366*768. But when I set the size to these values in Protractor, browser size launched is different than what is observed when done manually.

The values highlighted in the image below(shown using developer tool) works for me.

[image]

How do I set browser size so as to get browser window of this dimension?
Note - I do know how to set browser size in Protractor. Problem is that the size set does not match with required browser size, in this case 1366*768. Refer to image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set default browser window size in Protractor/WebdriverJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023567/how-to-set-default-browser-window-size-in-protractor-webdriverjs)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this for maximum width:

```
beforeEach(() => {
        browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    });
```

Also you can use this: for specific width:

```
var width = 1366;
var height = 768;
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
```