# Xvfb (xvfb-run) incorrect resolution

Tags: linux, google-chrome, protractor, headless, xvfb

i'm running protractor tests (chrome) headless and Xvfb or xvfb-run creates displays with incorrect resolution. I have two variants of tests starting:

```
Xvfb :10 -screen 0 1920x1200x24 -ac &
export DISPLAY=:10
<command>
```

or

```
xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-args='-screen 0, 1920x1200x24' <command>
```

but it creates screens with resolution 945x1180 (resolutiion can be a little bit smaller, it's chrome viewport).
BTW. If I change screen to 1, resolution will be 1050x1004

Comment: I'm using `xvfb-run -a -e /dev/stdout -s "-screen 0 2920x2580x24"` command and its working fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I search resolving of the problem almost 4 ours and, when I ask, answer was founded. Need to hardcode window size (I have chrome flag to start maximized and protractor parameter browser.driver.manage().window().maximize()). 
Answer from here helps me [How to set default browser window size in Protractor/WebdriverJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023567/how-to-set-default-browser-window-size-in-protractor-webdriverjs)

```
onPrepare: function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        browser.driver.executeScript(function() {
            return {
                width: window.screen.availWidth,
                height: window.screen.availHeight
            };
        }).then(function(result) {
            browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(result.width, result.height);
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: Could you please mark your answer as accepted, so this question disappear from list of unresolved questions?