# Setting Non-Chrome Window Size in Protractor Config For Selenium Tests

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox, protractor

So for Chrome, my understanding is that the following allows Protractor to decide the size of the window:

```
exports.config = {
    ...

    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: ['--window-size=1440,900', '-window-position=0,0']
        },
    },

    ...
}
```

What I am attempting to do is apply a similar method to other browsers, specifically Firefox and Internet Explorer.  I am specifically trying to avoid having the browser resize itself as part of the test process.  I decided to start my efforts with Firefox.

Searching for information in the protractor forums led me [here](https://github.com/juliemr/protractor-demo/tree/master/howtos/setFirefoxProfile) which recommends setting the getMultiCapabilities property of the exports.config object to a promise containing an encoded instance of firefox-profile.  Attempting to implement that solution caused any attempts to run my test suite to launch Chrome windows instead of Firefox.

As near as I can tell, the demo project in question is simply out of date.  Another Stack Overflow post led me towards trying this:

```
var FirefoxProfile = require('firefox-profile');
exports.config = {
    ...

    capabilities: firefoxCapabilities(),

    ...
}

function firefoxCapabilities() {
    var firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

    return {
        browserName: 'firefox',
        maxSessions: 1,
        firefox_profile : firefoxProfile,
    };
}
```

This almost, ALMOST seems to work.  It does at the very least launch Firefox, unlike the example in the demo project.  Unfortunately, as per [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1762) it seems as though I am supposed to use selenium-webdriver/firefox instead of firefox-profile.  Okay, all well and good, I just have to install another package since require can't find selenium-webdriver/firefox; oh wait, that should already be available?  Then it's getting complex, and I haven't even seen something to lead me to believe that creating my own Firefox profile will even let me set the window dimensions as I wish.

Changing tack, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023567/how-to-set-default-browser-window-size-in-protractor-webdriverjs) (specifically, the answer by Martin Sznapka) which seems to be suggesting a much simpler solution: using the onPrepare property to tell the driver what dimensions it should be using.  That said, IntelliJ is informing me that onPrepare is an unused function and, when I forge on and try to implement the solution anyway, nothing seems to change.  Variations don't seem to help.

So at this point I have spent more than a few hours trying simply to have protractor define the dimensions of the window as it does so easily for Chrome.  Between out-of-date demos, extra packages, and solutions that seem completely ineffective, I find myself wondering if I am even on the right track.

Any help or point-in-the-right-direction would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: As per request, here is my full exports.config object.  This launches Firefox but does not appear to have any effect on the window size.

```
exports.config = {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    directConnect: true,
    framework: 'jasmine',
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox',
        maxSessions: 1,
    },
    // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000
    },
    //Ensures that user is signed in before running tests
    onPrepare: function () {
        var disableNgAnimate = function () {
            angular.module('disableNgAnimate', []).run([
                '$animate', function ($animate) {
                    $animate.enabled(false);
                }
            ]);
        };
        browser.addMockModule('disableNgAnimate', disableNgAnimate);

        beforeEach(function () {
            browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; // prevents waiting on angular until timing out.
            browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(300, 300);
        });
    },
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['**/*.spec.js'],
    suites: {
        demo: 'demo/demo.spec.js',
        index: 'index/index.spec.js',
    }
};
```

Comment: You are saying "I am specifically trying to avoid having the browser resize itself as part of the test process", can you explain why you dont' want to use it? And secondly, you say "using the onPrepare property to tell the driver what dimensions it should be using". Can you paste the complete config, because it should work through `onPrepare`.

Comment: To be honest, it started because Chrome had such a simple solution available for the problem and a belief that another such solution would exist for other browsers, but admittedly after several hours of trying to figure it out it's more about principle than anything else: whether or not there IS a valid solution to be found, rather than whether or not it is the best solution for my problem.  I will edit my question shortly to contain a more complete config as per your request.