# "unable to connect to renderer" : Unable to resize or maximize the browser window using protractor with chrome beta

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, e2e-testing

I am using Protractor and jasmine.

I have Identified that chrome driver version: `2.32.498550 (latest)` is not compatible with the chrome beta `(Version 62.0.3202.18 (Official Build))`.

It breaks when the statements like

```
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize()
```

or

```
browser.driver.manage().window().getSize()
```

of the browser windows gets executed.

Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: Possible answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023567/how-to-set-default-browser-window-size-in-protractor-webdriverjs

Comment: @iamsankalp89 is correct in his answer/comments.  You can check the [chrome driver release notes](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) which clearly states "Supports Chrome v59-61".  v62 is not supported

Comment: Nice Question dear. it helps us

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this :

```
var width_size = 1024;
var height_size = 786;
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width_size , height_size );
```

Latest `chromedriver` does not support Latest chrome version, it support till  chrome 61

See this link: **http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.32/notes.txt**

It is issue of chromedriver

Comment: I have mentioned in my question, I am not able to use this statement as well.

Comment: Ok please paste your issue in log

Comment: Sure, I'll paste my log as well, but I am only getting this issue in chrome beta not on the stable version.

Comment: Latest chromedriver does not support Latest chrome version, it support till chrome 61, so some issues are there with chrome Version 62.0.3202.18

Answer (score 6):

Update your ChromeDriver version to 2.33 (e.g. using NuGet). You may have to end all running chromedriver.exe processes to get a successful build.

There was a bug in version 2.32 that caused resizing to fail for Chrome version 62. See [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46807816/5301903)

Answer (score 0):

It causes because page took long time to load , you need add additional line to your chromedriver option. Please refer the below link for more information : 
[Timed out receiving message from renderer in selenium](https://www.skptricks.com/2018/08/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-selenium.html)