# WebDriverError: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Meta -

OS: OSX 10.12.6 (16G29)

```
~./node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver  -v
ChromeDriver 2.32.498537 (cb2f855cbc7b82e20387eaf9a43f6b99b6105061)

~ $ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7/Contents/Home

~ $ node -v
v6.11.2
```

Browser:

> Chrome Version 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Browser Version:

> 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Expected Behavior -

> A Chrome session should start and the script should execute till the end

Actual Behavior -

> The browser is started but the script immedialy crashes.

Code:

```
> ucb-client@2.97.3 selenium-local /Users/Georgios/Development/rocket-internet/ucb-client
> node test/automation-tests/testcases/happy-path/Local_Guest_Cash.js

/Users/Georgios/Development/rocket-internet/ucb-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2634
        throw error;
        ^

WebDriverError: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.62)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498537 (cb2f855cbc7b82e20387eaf9a43f6b99b6105061),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
    at WebDriverError (/Users/Georgios/Development/rocket-internet/ucb-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:5)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/Users/Georgios/Development/rocket-internet/ucb-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:529:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/Users/Georgios/Development/rocket-internet/ucb-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/Users/Georgios/Development/rocket-internet/ucb-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 720)
    at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (/Users/Georgios/Development/rocket-internet/ucb-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:807:17)
    at Window.setSize (/Users/Georgios/Development/rocket-internet/ucb-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1677:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Georgios/Development/rocket-internet/ucb-client/test/automation-tests/testcases/happy-path/Local_Guest_Cash.js:8:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
Actual script (beginning)

require('chromedriver');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
By = webdriver.By,
until = webdriver.until;
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
var timeout = 15000;
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are using the chromediver 2.32 and in the [release notes](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt) there is written that the support is for *Chrome v59-61*

As browser you have:

```
Chrome Version 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

So, from [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads), you should use the 2.33

Comment: That's right! Download latest version from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.33/ and bug will disapeare.

Comment: just to note that it's not a clean cut, some things are not working (backward compatibility wise), but it seems minor for now (around Window positions which wasn't much of a use anyways).

Comment: Really thanks, this solved my problem. I was running an old version of chromedriver and Chrome 62

Comment: FYI, this is specifically an instance of https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1918

Comment: `npm install -g chromedriver` on Chrome 65 and chromedriver v. `2.31` (which then updated to v. `2.36`) solved it for me!

Comment: I'm using latest chrome version 80 for Chrome Browser 80 but ,for me it is still displaying same error message...

Answer (score 43):

I had similar error. But versions were matching: I was using Chrome 65 with driver version 2.38.

I spent long time, trying to understand the issue.
At the end, found that it was caused by empty `/etc/hosts` file. Apparently Chrome communicates via `localhost`, and if such entry missing in `/etc/hosts` - it will crash.

So, make sure, it has entry like this:

`127.0.0.1  localhost`

Comment: I had this problem with Mac OS X 10.13.6, Selenium 3.13.0, Chromedriver 2.41, and Chrome 67. Adding the line

`127.0.0.1 localhost loopback`

to `/etc/hosts` fixed it right up.

Comment: I spent a couple nights looking into this issue and a lot of the solutions instruct you to make sure your versions are all up to date/in sync: selenium, chrome, chromedriver ... if your versions are all in sync and updated then this is what you need to do. This worked for me editing the /etc/hosts file with TOB's code comment.

Comment: How on EARTH did you find that? My god, I wasted an entire day.

Comment: That solves my problem. I checked and all versions were fine but now I can recall, I changed the `localhost` entry to another host on some day.  Changing to `127.0.0.1  localhost ` worked. I wasted two days figuring out. Thank you!

Comment: going by the comments above this saved me a fair bit of time as well.

Comment: You just saved me an hour :] I will petition to have the error improved.

Comment: I've changed as per above but still for me coming as "[1581500745.657][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, giving up." ,can any one help me

Answer (score 1):

Here's an `brew` addendum to @davide-patti solution. :)

When I was getting the error `unable to connect to renderer`, I learned from 
@davide-patti that I was using an older version of chromedriver, v2.32.  But I was unable to upgrade my `chromedriver` with home`brew`, as I received continually: `No available formula with the name "chromedriver"`.

This article helped me a lot to upgrade to v2.33+.

**About: Error: No available formula with the name "chromedriver"**
https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/4089

Answer (score 1):

It causes because page took long time to load , you need add additional line to your script

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\selenium\\chromedriver_2.41\\chromedriver.exe");
//mention the below chrome option to solve timeout exception issue
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
// Instantiate the chrome driver
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Running *headful* chrome in AWS lambda was giving me this error. Setting the page load strategy fixed the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IT is because driver is not closed and you try run again.
Try to reboot or change port id.
options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9230")
You can change this port.
Thanks