# Automation Testing Error : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new in automation testing and I am facing the following error. I am not able to proceed further. Can someone help me out in this :
{Error}

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8) on port 47649
Only local connections are allowed.
Feb 06, 2018 4:48:10 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.140)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.03 seconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'ALPSCMO-QA10', ip: '10.50.7.126', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8), userDataDir=C:\Users\manand\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir6152_17631}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=64.0.3282.140, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 3afbe7096bc143edfa25f5ae8616b830
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:694)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.maximize(RemoteWebDriver.java:925)
    at AutomationFramework.FirstTestClass.main(FirstTestClass.java:19)
```

Comment: please, add your capacity and describe how you run driver in your test

Comment: This is a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807596/webdrivererror-disconnected-unable-to-connect-to-renderer

Answer (score 3):

The error says it all :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.140)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.03 seconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'ALPSCMO-QA10', ip: '10.50.7.126', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** among the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using **`chromedriver=2.31`**
- Release Notes of [**`chromedriver=2.31`**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.31/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> **`Supports Chrome v58-60`**

- You are using **`chrome=64.0`**
- Release Notes of [**`ChromeDriver v2.35`**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> **`Supports Chrome v62-64`**

- Your **`Selenium Client`** is not getting detected, so we are unable to know the **`Selenium Client`** version.
- Your **`JDK version`** is **`1.8.0_112`** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK version* , *Selenium Client version* , *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.31*) and the *Chrome Browser* version (*v64.0*)

### Solution

- Upgrade `JDK` to  recent levels **`JDK Version 8 Update 151`**.
- Upgrade `Selenium` to  current levels **`Version 3.8.1`**.
- Upgrade `ChromeDriver` to  **`ChromeDriver v2.35`** level.
- Keep `Chrome` to  **`Chrome v64.x`** levels. ([`as per ChromeDriver v2.35 release notes`](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt))
- If your base *Chrome* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of Chrome.
- Execute your `Test`.

Comment: i wish i could upvote another time - that's a really good answer!

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should Update to latest ChromeDriver that is 2.33. Hope it will resolve your issues.