# Unable to open Chrome browser using selenium 3.10.0

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using following configuration:

```
Windows 7
Java: 1.8.0_91
Selenium: 3.10.0
Chrome browser: 62.0
Chrome Driver : 2.34
```

While running found below error:

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception
>   from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
>     (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.62)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940 
> (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 938 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '3.10.0', revision: '176b4a9', time: '2018-03-02T19:03:16.397Z'
>   System info: host: 'OFFICE-PC', ip: '192.168.1.230', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
>   Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automation Testing Error : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48642014/automation-testing-error-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-disconnected)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmmm... Looks familiar.

Have you checked that you are not using a 32bit ChromeDriver for a 64bit Chrome browser?