# Selenium and Chrome Compatibility (v67 + 2.38 chromedriver)

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently trying to run a python program on my linux box.  I keep getting this error:

I am using Chrome version 67 and Selenium chromedriver of 2.38.  Which I thought were compatible?  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created exception
from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.62)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Linux 3.13.0-92-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: They are compatible according to https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads, double confirm you download the correct binary, you can try to download again from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.38/

Answer (score 0):

As per your error stack trace as you are using **chromedriver=2.38** and **chrome=67.0** this issue must not have arised.

Even the discussion [Get a "WebDriverException: disconnected: unable to receive message from renderer" error when switching browser windows](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=401) doesn't provides any proper conclusion. However you can try a couple of upgrade/cleanup steps as follows:

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.12.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Keep *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.38**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v67.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.38 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

You will find similar discussions in:

- [Automation Testing Error : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48642014/automation-testing-error-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-disconnected/48642804#48642804)
- [Error [SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 20.000 while executing the testsuite through Selenium on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051117/error-severe-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-20-000-while-executin/50051844#50051844)