# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created disconnected:unable to send message to renderer error with ChromeDriver and Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I try to run this simple program on Java with Selenium:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class MySelenium {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("First Selenium");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\automation\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.seleniumhq.org/");
        driver.quit();              
    }
}
```

But on running shows the following error:

[image]

How can i fixed this error ?

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Did you google the error message? What did you find? What did you try based on what you found? Do a little searching and update your question with the results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebDriverError: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807596/webdrivererror-disconnected-unable-to-connect-to-renderer)

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created 
disconnected: unable to send message to renderer
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

I suspect your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using.

As per the snapshot you have provided the following set of binaries you are using looks fine to me:

- *JDK*: **1.8.0_191**
- *Selenium*: **3.14.0**
- *ChromeDriver*: **2.43**
- *Chrome*: **69.0**

### Analysis & Solution

- As per [Unable to receive message from renderer error using chrome driver 2.27](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1651) another pottential reason can be presence of **antivirus** within your *localhost* which you need to **disable**.
- Ensure that **/etc/hosts** on your system contains the following entry:

  ```
  127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
  #or
  127.0.0.1 localhost loopback
  ```
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v68-70*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.43 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

---

### Reference

You can find a related discussion in [Automation Testing Error : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48642014/automation-testing-error-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-disconnected)

---

### tl;dr

As per [ChromeDriver 2.34 doesn't wait until iframe content loads after switching into iframe](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2198&can=1&q=2198&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary) this issue was also observed with **ChromeDriver 2.38** and **Chrome 67+** combo and was related to **static iframes** (part of the originally loaded DOM) which seem to work correctly even till **Chrome 66**.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JDK 1.8.0_181. I had the same issue after updating to JDK 1.8.0_191.