# Unable to run the selenium script while connected to the LAN

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Unable to run the selenium script while connected to the LAN, however it works fine when connected to the WIFI. I have kept all the proxy settings same.
Below is the code:

```
    String exePath = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

OS: Mac 10.11.6
Selenium: 2.53
Also tried with 3.8.1
ChromeDriver: 2.33.2
Chrome: V60.
Eclipse Oxygen.

Getting Below mentioned error message:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506106 (8a06c39c4582fbfbab6966dbb1c38a9173bfb1a2) on port 21777
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
(Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.113)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506106 (8a06c39c4582fbfbab6966dbb1c38a9173bfb1a2),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.65 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'
System info: host: '01hw382197', ip: '172.25.155.171', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '9.0.4'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
(Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.113)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506106 (8a06c39c4582fbfbab6966dbb1c38a9173bfb1a2),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.65 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'
```

The main reason is the binaries you are using are **incompatible** as :

- You are using *ChromeDriver* **v2.33** of **(2017-10-03)**
- Your *Chrome Browser* version is **60.x**
- Your *Selenium Client* version is **2.53.1** of **time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'**

So there is a time gap of almost *2 years* between the release of *Selenium Client v2.53.1* and *ChromeDriver v2.33*

### Solution

- Upgrade your *Selenium Client* to recent ***Selenium v3.9.1*** level.
- Upgrade your *ChromeDriver* to recent ***ChromeDriver=2.35*** level.
- As per the Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver=2.35*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt) upgrade your *Chrome Browser* to ***Chrome v62-64*** levels.
- If your base *Chrome Browser* version is too old uninstall *Chrome Browser* through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent released GA version of *Chrome Browser*
- Run [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool regularly to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*
- Execute your *Tests*

---

### Update

As you mentioned you are *unable to run the script while connected to the LAN but works fine when connected to the WIFI* you need to ensure the following :

- Ports used by the *WebDriver* variants (*GeckoDriver* / *ChromeDriver* / *IEDriverServer*) are not used by any other Software/Services over the LAN.
- Ports (range of ports) are not blocked by the LAN Admins for specific purpose.
- Firewall is disabled.

Comment: I understand that I am using the old versions, but it is intentionally done by me. However if this would be a version issue then my script will fail while connecting to WIFI as well, which is not happening in my case. Chrome version I am using 60 so compatible chromedriver is 2.33,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760761/unable-to-launch-chrome-from-selenium-while-using-mac-system/48761606?noredirect=1#comment84524906_48761606

please check in this post, while everything was of latest version, then also I was unable to run it. Please help

Comment: Added an update to my answer. Let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DebanjanB:
1. How to check whether the ports are not used by any other app in mac? I have tried couple of terminal commands which i found in google but couldn't find any relevant option
2. No ports are blocked, also I have run a command to open all the ports.
3. Firewall is disabled.
Please advice what needs to be done next.