# How to resolve 'unable to connect to renderer' using chrome v 74.0.3729.131 with chromedriver 74.0.3729.6

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am unable to establish a connection using ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6 with the latest Chrome version 74.0.3729.131.

The error message I am getting:

> ```
> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
> session not created
> from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
> (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
> (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6         (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch- heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
> ```

Below the code, which has worked with Chrome version 73 and ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File (ExtensionPath));
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Anybody else having this issue and has found a solution?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this query to solve for my issue: [WebDriverError: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807596/webdrivererror-disconnected-unable-to-connect-to-renderer)

I opened and unlocked the /private/etc/hosts file and added: 127.0.0.1  localhost

However, I am unclear why this had suddenly become an issue.