# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: error message is displayed while running parallel execution

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: error message is displayed while running parallel execution after configuring --remote-debugging-port=9222 chrome option. How to fix this issue ?

Note : (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) error message is displayed if it is not configured --remote-debugging-port=9222 chrome option, so I have added remote debugging port in chrome options

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); 
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized"); 
chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); 
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation"); 
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); 
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
chromeOptions.addArguments("allow-running-insecure-content");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");  
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

**Error message :**

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
     (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
    Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
    System info: host: 'fffffff', ip: 'xyz', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
    Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
            Ordinal0 [0x00B30C83+1707139]
            Ordinal0 [0x00A968F1+1075441]
            Ordinal0 [0x00A0DFC9+516041]
            Ordinal0 [0x0099D373+54131]
            Ordinal0 [0x009BBFD7+180183]
            Ordinal0 [0x009BBDDD+179677]
            Ordinal0 [0x009B9D4B+171339]
            Ordinal0 [0x009A1D4A+73034]
            Ordinal0 [0x009A2DC0+77248]
            Ordinal0 [0x009A2D59+77145]
            Ordinal0 [0x00AABB67+1162087]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00BCA966+508998]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00BCA6A4+508292]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00BDF7B7+594583]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00BCB1D6+511158]
            Ordinal0 [0x00AA402C+1130540]
            Ordinal0 [0x00AAD4CB+1168587]
            Ordinal0 [0x00AAD633+1168947]
            Ordinal0 [0x00AC5B35+1268533]
            BaseThreadInitThunk [0x770362C4+36]
            RtlSubscribeWnfStateChangeNotification [0x77411E39+1081]
            RtlSubscribeWnfStateChangeNotification [0x77411E04+1028]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebDriverError: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807596/webdrivererror-disconnected-unable-to-connect-to-renderer)

Comment: @demouser123 I have fixed rendered issue and it's showing different issue

Answer (score 0):

```
--remote-debugging-port=9222
```

this option is used when you are trying to run your tests on chrome browser which is already running on this port 9222

**and same is error message which says chrome.exe is not running**

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
     (**The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running**, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

So see your test case what it is doing, I believe you are trying to capture already running chrome node registered with grid.

so this might also required

```
cp.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222");
```

Full working example here

1. start chrome browser using command 
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="C:\autoprofile"
2. The code to connect the browser is :-
   package com.example;
   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

   ```
   public class ChromeDebugger {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       ChromeOptions cp = new ChromeOptions();
       cp.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222");
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
               "./src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
       ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cp);
       System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
       driver.findElement(By.linkText("About")).click();
       System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
         }
   ```

   }

Comment: I'm not using GRID.  I am executing script from CI Server (Bamboo).  How to fix this ?