# How to solve selenium exceptions?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using python, and the error becomes like this:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: unable to send message to renderer
  (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.198)
```

How should I solve it?

Comment: Let's see your code -  not just the exception

Comment: I believe this question has already been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807596/webdrivererror-disconnected-unable-to-connect-to-renderer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.