# Element is not clickable at point in headless mode. But when we remove headless from protractor.conf.js it is working fine.

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

```
element(by.className('cuppa-dropdown')).element(by.className('dropdown-list')).element(by.className('list-area')).element(by.tagName('li')).click();
```

actually this element is in pop up. ANd it is woring fine in **headless** mode. But as we need to automate the test cases by build in vsts we need to execute test in headless mode

**Failed: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (863, 343)**     (Session info: headless chrome=63.0.3239.84)     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)

Comment: try to change the browser window size before starting your tests and check if that's the problem. refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023567/how-to-set-default-browser-window-size-in-protractor-webdriverjs

Comment: any how we are using this in beforeeach() browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

Comment: issue is occuring becaus of headless mode i.e.,            args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800x600"],

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As answered above try to set window size as argument for chrome

```
chromeOptions: {
                args: [
                    '--window-size=1920,1080'],
```

and

```
setTimeout(function() {
                browser.driver.executeScript(function() {
                    return {
                        width: window.screen.availWidth,
                        height: window.screen.availHeight
                    };
                }).then(function(result) {
                    browser.driver.manage().window().setPosition(0,0);
                    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(result.width, result.height);
                });
            });
```

Comment: where to use setTimeout() function

Comment: we are using browser.driver.manage().window().maximize() in beforeeach()

Comment: inside onPrepare() like here https://github.com/andriyze/proTR/blob/021c9fed9c203c358a0f64e68696ece2c1e8db34/protractor.conf.js#L50

Comment: Previously i was using args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800x600"]. Now as you mentioned args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1080"], it is working fine. Thanks for the help

Comment: Setting the window size alone solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: @vikasbiradar you have to set it in protractor.conf.js

Answer (score 5):

It's working fine when changing chrome options in config file from

```
args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1280x1024"]
```

to

```
args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1080"]
```

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Where we have to edit this ?? Where is config file for this ??

Comment: @Rajan at e2e/protractor.conf.js: config > capabilities > chromeOptions > args