# How to use headless chrome with selenium to scroll AND click elements?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

Adding the command line `--headless` to my chrome driver resulted with few problems in some of my automation testcases.

Some elements where not interactable until I added the argument `--window-size=1920,1080`, but on the other hand, adding this argument resulted with a new problem with testcases that uses JQuery's scrolling function (e.g `$('#element').scrollBy(...)`).

To the intractability problem I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776774/element-is-not-clickable-at-point-in-headless-mode-but-when-we-remove-headless), and to the scrolling problem I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48257870/headless-chrome-with-selenium-can-only-find-ways-to-scroll-non-headless). But what should I do with `--window-size` which solves one and creates an other problem? and why does it affect scrolling at all?

======

Scrolling Error Info:

no error is thrown but scrolling simply does not work.

======

Not interactable Error Info:

```
TimeoutError: An error occurred while running .click() command on <Element [name=@openFiltersView]>:   (Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.88),  (Driver info: chromedriver=87.0.4280.20 (c99e81631faa0b2a448e658c0dbd8311fb04ddbd-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#355}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18363 x86_64); element not interactable
   {"status":-1,"state":"","value":{"message":"element not interactable","error":["  (Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.88)","  (Driver info: chromedriver=87.0.4280.20 (c99e81631faa0b2a448e658c0dbd8311fb04ddbd-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#355}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18363 x86_64)"]},"errorStatus":11,"error":"element not interactable","httpStatusCode":200}
```