# How to make this a separate function in typescript?

Tags: typescript, protractor

There is an inbuilt method to get the browser width and height in protractor or webdriver API

```
browser.manage().window().getSize().then(function(size) {
return size.width;
});
```

How can i convert above in a single method ?

I want to use that method in an if condition within my tests 
e.g.

```
if (width > 500) {
it ('test following', () => {
expectations goes here
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `manage().window().getSize()` has to be executed in the Protractor's control flow which would not be yet initialized if you call it outside of `before*()`, `after*()` or `it()` contexts.

Just put your condition into the test itself:

```
function getWidth() {
    return browser.manage().window().getSize().then(function(size) { 
        return size.width
    });
}

it ('test following', () => {
    getWidth().then(function (width) {
        if (width > 500) {
            // test something
        }
        else {
            console.log("Skipped testing something");
        }
    });
})
```

---

Or, depending on your use case, you can set the dimensions of the browser window for a specific capability ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40284389/771848)) in your protractor config and specify tests that would be executed for this capability - this should eliminate the need to do this check in the test itself.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But what does it mean when you say "manage().window().getSize() has to be executed in the Protractor's control flow" ? Is it correct approach to make a method mentioned in your example. Looks like that method is actually not doing anything, we are resolving the same promise twice ?

Comment: @Naveen no, the promise is gonna be resolved once when the control flow queue dequeues this promise. Also, here is a link to the control flow doc: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md.