# Selenium2 can't fill password field

Tags: php, html, selenium-webdriver

Problem with Selenium2 test not filling in password field. Says element is not visible. I have included the error, the selenium test, and code below.

**Error**

> Failed to test manage account settings functionality in
>   ManageAccountSettingsCept.php Sorry, I couldn't fill field
>   "#users_password","myPassword": Behat\Mink\Exception\ElementException:
>   Exception thrown by (//html/descendant-or-self::*[@id =
>   'users_password'])[1] Element is not currently visible and so may not
>   be interacted with

**Selenium test**

```
$I = new SeleniumGuy($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Test Manage Account Settings functionality');
$I->amOnPage('/login');
$I->fillField('#users_email','email@email.com');
$I->fillField('#users_password','myPassword');
```

**Code**

```
<div class="core_component_item core_diagonal_input">
     <input value="" name="users_password" id="users_password" type="password"  style="border:none;margin-left:8px;margin-top:6px;color:#33322e;background-color:transparent;outline:0;resize:none; width:220px;border:solid 1px transparent; " class="core_input_text">
</div>
```

Comment: It claims it's not visible, is this true? What happens if you remove those `transparent` borders & background? (And why would you have 2 competing `border` definitions?) Another thing to try is to add a `placeholder`, perhaps that triggers something.

Comment: I think you have another element with the same id on the page, check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16162026/716691

Comment: another link: http://www.seleniumwebdriver.com/google-selenium-webdriver/elementnotvisibleexception-element-is-not-currently-visible-and-so-may-not-be-i/ hope these help

Comment: I have the similar problem, it seems some javascripts affected it