# Set browser permission to allow full screen in sauce lab testing (firefox browser)

Tags: angularjs, firefox, protractor, saucelabs, end-to-end

Currently the firefox browser deny the full screen, so when I test my code, it cannot go up to full screen.  Is there a place I could change this setting?  Is this something I could put on the test configuration json?

Answer (score 2):

You can maximize the browser window via [`maximize()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.Window.prototype.maximize):

```
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

If you want to apply it for all of your tests, call it in `onPrepare()` inside the protractor config.

See also:

- [How to set default browser window size in Protractor/WebdriverJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023567/how-to-set-default-browser-window-size-in-protractor-webdriverjs)
- [Make protractor test occupy the entire screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493856/make-protractor-test-occupy-the-entire-screen)

Comment: i'm working on a video player.  I think the above solution will set the browser size, but somehow firefox does not allow my video player to be at full screen (I think there is a permission setting).  Is there any way to change the permission setting in the configuration?  Sorry that i didn't make this clear earlier.

Comment: @JeffHsu ok, no problem. How are you trying to make the player full screen?

Comment: If somebody have a solution to this problem please post it