# Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

My Protrator code is

```
element(by.dataHook("delete-button")).click();
```

Getting:

> Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

HTML source:

```
<button class="md-icon-but" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="g" translate="loc" aria-label="Delete" title="Delete">
    <md-icon md-svg-icon="ass" data-hook="delete-button" class="ng-scope" aria-hidden="true"><svg xmlns="ht" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fit="" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false"><path d="M6 19c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7H6v12zM19 4h-3.5l-1-1h-5l-1 1H5v2h14V4z"></path></svg></md-icon>
    <div class="md"></div></b>
```

How to resolve it and and make a successful click?

Comment: '<button class="md-icon-but" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="g" translate="loc" aria-label="Delete" title="Delete">
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="ass" data-hook="delete-button" class="ng-scope" aria-hidden="true"><svg xmlns="ht" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fit="" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false"><path d="M6 19c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7H6v12zM19 4h-3.5l-1-1h-5l-1 1H5v2h14V4z"></path></svg></md-icon>
      <div class="md"></div></b>'

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it is just that you need to [maximize the browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023567/how-to-set-default-browser-window-size-in-protractor-webdriverjs):

```
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Note that on Chrome+Mac, currently you [have to do it differently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29857043/771848).

---

Here is the set of other things that also helped others:

- verify that there are *no other elements matching the locator*. You can get this error if there is an another element matching the locator that is actually invisible.
- wait for the [element to be clickable](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeClickable):

  ```
  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions,
      elm = $("button[title=Delete]");

  browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(elm), 5000);
  ```
- [scroll into view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) of the element:

  ```
  var elm = $("button[title=Delete]");
  browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elm);
  ```
- click [via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562061/webdriver-click-vs-javascript-click):

  ```
  var elm = $("button[title=Delete]");
  browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elm);
  ```
- *move to element* and click via "browser actions":

  ```
  var elm = $("button[title=Delete]");
  browser.actions()
      .mouseMove(elm)
      .click()
      .perform();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the element with id 'abc' to be clickable.
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable($('#abc')), 5000);
```